Sourcemap, workspace, postcss breaking sync for css from element to source tab in chrome dev tools
My files are setup as such:
fe/css/styles.css
public/css/styles.min.css
public/css/styles.min.css.map
My goal was to be able to edit css in elements panel and have it be persisted in the original file.
By original file I refer to the file from which generated file was created, authored css file, styles.css, and not styles.min.css.
Source map associated with styles.min.css.map loads correctly.
In elements panel it shows original file when and clicking does take you to correct place in the original file. However, if you make changes in element panel they are NOT reflected in original file. And if you refresh the changes are gone, even though original file folder is added in the workspace panel.
Hovering over the original file in the workspace panel also say file linked to source map styles.min.css.map
i have tried disabling the hashing in postcss
i have tried inlining the sourcemap
i have tried removing external links
i have tried removing prefixes
i have tried adding both generated folder and authored folder into the workspace
